# SQL/Python - Adding list (with multiple entries) to SQL String

Tags: python, sql

I have a list in Python i.e:

```
['E/123', 'E/145']
```

I want to add this to a SQL statement that I made:

```
WHERE GrantInformation.GrantRefNumber LIKE 'E/123' 
OR GrantInformation.GrantRefNumber LIKE 'E/145'
```

The code I have is:

```
items = []
i = 0
while 1:
    i += 1
    item = input('Enter item %d: '%i)
    if item == '':
        break
    items.append(item)
    print(items)

refList = " OR GrantInformation.GrantRefNumber LIKE ".join(items)
```

The problem is, when I insert that String into my SQL it is a String so it is looking for `WHERE GrantInformation.GrantRefNumber Like 'ES/P004355/1 OR GrantInformation.GrantRefNumber LIKE ES/P001452/1'`

Which obviously returns nothing as `'ES/P004355/1 OR GrantInformation.GrantRefNumber LIKE ES/P001452/1'` does not appear in the field.

How do i do it so the `' GrantInformation.GrantRefNumber LIKE '` is not a String?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred way to do this, is to use a ORM like [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org), which 
does the query construction for you and you dont have to make the string concentrations yourself.

`join()`, adds the string between all the items in the array, that is passed as argument. You would need to add the condition into the array as well:

```
>>> items = ['A', 'B']
>>> " OR ".join(["GrantInformation.GrantRefNumber LIKE '%s'" % num for num in items])
"GrantInformation.GrantRefNumber LIKE 'A' OR GrantInformation.GrantRefNumber LIKE 'B'"
```

Comment: Hey Maurice, I will look at SQLAlchemy for my next project (thanks!). I am just testing the code now although will have to remove the quote marks around the string somehow as the SQL wont take them :)

Comment: Hey, I dont suppose you know of a way to remove the quote strings from the string that your code produces? I tried finalList = refList[1:-1] but that just removed the first and last character (and not the quote strings)?

Comment: Fixed it. Thank you very much :)